# Can't optimise mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am running a query to retrieve some game levels from a MySQL database. The query itself takes around 0.00025 seconds to execute on a base that contains 40 level strings. I thought it was satisfactory, until I got a message from the website host telling me to optimise the below-mentioned query, or the script will be removed since it is pushing a lot of strain onto their servers.

I tried optimising by using explain and explain extended and adjusting the columns accordingly(adding indexes), but am always getting the same performance. What I noticed also is that MySQL didn't use indexes where they were available but instead did a full-table scan.

Results from EXPLAIN EXTENDED:

```
table   id  select_type  type   possible_keys   key     key_len   ref            rows   Extra
users   1   SIMPLE       ALL    PRIMARY,id      NULL     NULL     NULL           7      Using temporary; Using filesort
AllTime 1   SIMPLE       ref    PRIMARY,userid  PRIMARY  4        Test.users.id  1
```

query:

```
    SELECT users.nickname, AllTime.userid, AllTime.id, AllTime.levelname, AllTime.levelstr
    FROM AllTime
    INNER JOIN users
    ON AllTime.userid=users.id
    ORDER BY AllTime.id DESC
    LIMIT ($value_from_php),20;
```

The tables:
users

```
| id(int)                   | nickname(varchar) | 
| (Primary, Auto_increment) |                   |
|---------------------------|-------------------|
| 1                         | username1         |
| 2                         | username2         |
| 3                         | username3         |
| ...                       | ...               |
```

and AllTime

```
| id(int)                   | userid(int) | levelname(varchar) | levelstr(text) |
| (Primary, Auto_increment) | (index)     |                    |                |
|---------------------------|-------------|--------------------|----------------|
| 1                         | 2           | levelname1         | levelstr1      |
| 2                         | 2           | levelname2         | levelstr2      |
| 3                         | 3           | levelname3         | levelstr3      |
| 4                         | 1           | levelname4         | levelstr4      |
| 5                         | 1           | levelname5         | levelstr5      |
| 6                         | 1           | levelname6         | levelstr6      |
| 7                         | 2           | levelname7         | levelstr7      |
```

Is there a way to optimize this query or would I be better off by calling two consecutive queries from php just to avoid the warning?

I am just learning MySQL, so please take that information into account when replying, thank you :)

Comment: A query that is taking a small fraction of a second should not be the one causing this problem -- unless you are calling it hundreds of times per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using InnoDB.

For an INNER JOIN, MySQL typically starts with the table with the fewest rows, in this case `users`. However, since you just want the latest 20 `AllTime` records joined with the corresponding `user` records, you actually should start with `AllTime` since with the `LIMIT`, it will be the smaller data set.

Use STRAIGHT_JOIN to force the join order:

```
SELECT users.nickname, AllTime.userid, AllTime.id, AllTime.levelname, 
   AllTime.levelstr
FROM AllTime
STRAIGHT_JOIN users
ON users.id = AllTime.userid
ORDER BY AllTime.id DESC
LIMIT ($value_from_php),20;
```

It should be able to use the primary key on the `AllTime` table and follow it in descending order. It'll grab all the data on the same pages as it goes.

It should also use the primary key on the users table to grab the id and nickname. If there are more than just two columns, you might add a multi-column covering index on (id, nickname) to improve the speed.

If you can, convert the `levelstr` column to `VARCHAR` so that the data is stored on the same page as the rest of the data, otherwise, it has to go fetch the text columns separately. This assumes that your columns are under the 8000 byte row limit for InnoDB. There is no way to avoid the `USING TEMPORARY` unless you get rid of the text column.

Most likely, your host has identified this query by using the slow query log, which can identify all queries that don't use an index, or they may have red flagged it because of the `Using temporary`.

Comment: Thank you very much :D
The host has identified the query as such because it wasn't using indexes.
Adding the covering index seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like the query has a problem.

1. Review the application code. Most likely the issue is in the code
2. Check [MySQL query execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)

   - possibly you are missing an index
3. Make sure you cache the data in Application and [Database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) (fyi, sometimes you can load the whole database into Application memory)
4. Make sure you use a connection pool
5. Create a view (a very small chance for improvement)
6. Try to remove the "Order By" clause (again a very small chance it will improve the performance)

Answer (score 0):

> The query itself takes around **0.00025 seconds**  ...  I got a message from the website host telling me to optimise the below-mentioned query, or the script will be removed since it is pushing **a lot of strain onto their servers**.

Ask the website host for more details about why this query has been flagged for attention.  A query that trivial is not going to cause strain on anything unless it is being called very frequently.

Find out how many times that query is being run.  I will bet you a nickel that your site is getting hammered by a bot and being executed hundreds or thousands of times per minute.  If so, then that's your real problem.

Comment: I have sent a mail to the administrators a few days ago and the server has indeed been under a DDOS attack with over 3GB/s of incoming data, but not through any of my scripts. The message I received has probably been issued as a warning, as Marcus Adams pointed out in the reply, because it isn't using indexes.
Thank you for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT ($value_from_php),20;` -- if $value_form_php is huge, then the query is slow.  This is because all the 'old' pages need to be scanned before getting to the 20 you need.

By "remembering where you left off" you can make every page equally fast.  See this for further details: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination